# Jackrabbit Oak merge not saving changes

Tags: jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I just started to look into Jackrabbit Oak 1.7.5 and I can't get my changes saved - this test fails on the last assertion:

```
public class JCRTest {

@Test
public void testCommit() throws CommitFailedException {
    final NodeStore ns = new MemoryNodeStore();
    final String imagesFolder = "images";
    NodeState rootState = ns.getRoot();

    //newly created store does not have nodes
    assertThat(rootState.getChildNode(imagesFolder).exists(), is(equalTo(false)));

    NodeBuilder rootBuilder = rootState.builder();
    //adding a node called 'images'
    rootBuilder.child(imagesFolder);

    //it is still not going to be shown since we are working in our own 'state'
    assertThat(rootState.getChildNode(imagesFolder).exists(), is(equalTo(false)));

    //merging the changes into root
    ns.merge(rootBuilder, EmptyHook.INSTANCE, CommitInfo.EMPTY);

    //expecting to see the 'images' folder
    assertThat(rootState.getChildNode(imagesFolder).exists(), is(equalTo(true)));
}
}
```

Comment: So... changing the last line to:           `assertThat(ns.getRoot().getChildNode(imagesFolder).exists(), is(equalTo(true)));` made it work but I would still like to understand the reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NodeState` (rootState in your test) is a snapshot of the repository. After you merge your changes, you need to get head of the repository again (i.e. do `rootState = ns.getRoot()` again before asserting).